# How do I read user input and forward it to another application in bash, preserving quoted arguments?

Tags: bash, user-input

I am trying to pass bash user input read using the `read` command to an external application, as if what the user wrote were arguments in bash.

In the following example, I've used a function rather than an external application, but that *should be* irrelevant. This is the script I am using:

```
foo() { while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do echo "$1"; shift; done }
read -p "Write something: " bar
foo "${bar}"
foo ${bar}
```

What I write when I am asked to write something:

```
"a b" "c d" e\ f g\"h
```

What I expect to see as output:

```
a b
c d
e f
g"h
```

What I actually see: (the first line is first call to `foo()`, the rest of the lines are from the second call)

```
"a b" "c d" e f g"h
"a
b"
"c
d"
e
f
g"h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `set -x` before you start, bash will echo the commands as it's trying to run them. In particular, you can see that bash is expanding $bar before it gets passed to foo():

```
$ foo ${bar}
+ foo '"a' 'b"' '"c' 'd"' e f 'g"h'
```

The answer is to use eval, however this isn't *quite* as straightforward as it might seem:

```
$ eval foo ${bar]
+ eval foo '"a' 'b"' '"c' 'd"' e f 'g"h'
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

In this case, you need to escape both the quote and the backslash:

```
$ read -p "Write something: " bar
+ read -p 'Write something: ' bar
Write something: "a b" "c d" e\ f g\\\"h
$ eval foo ${bar}
+ eval foo '"a b" "c d" e f g\"h'
++ foo 'a b' 'c d' e f 'g"h'
++ '[' 5 -gt 0 ']'
++ echo 'a b'
a b
++ shift
++ '[' 4 -gt 0 ']'
++ echo 'c d'
c d
++ shift
++ '[' 3 -gt 0 ']'
++ echo e
e
++ shift
++ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
++ echo f
f
++ shift
++ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
++ echo 'g"h'
g"h
++ shift
++ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use eval to re-interpret the quotes inside the variable:

```
eval foo "$bar"

a b
c d
e f
g"h
```

EDIT: This is unsecure and requires validating the source string to escape all bash-special chars.

Comment: If `$bar` is `"a b ; ls"` then the `ls` command would actually be executed by `eval`. You shouldn't recommend this, or you should put it in bold that it's a very risky command every time you mention eval. Security is not a big issue in my particular case, but it would suck if a `";"` would be enough to break the whole script.

Comment: Right, I've just overlooked this.